# MongoDB date format in strict mode

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-java

1. Using MongoDB java driver, applying toJson() method on Document will get a JSON representation of this document with JsonMode set to STRICT.
   The following epoch format is used for dates: { "$date" : "dateAsMilliseconds" }
2. Using mongoexport, we get an ISO-8601 format.
3. Seen in official doc ( https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/ ) :

   - In Strict mode, date is an ISO-8601 date format with a mandatory time zone field following the template YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.mmm<+/-Offset>.
   - The MongoDB JSON parser currently does not support loading ISO-8601 strings representing dates prior to the Unix epoch. When formatting pre-epoch dates and dates past what your system’s time_t type can hold, the following format is used:
     { "$date" : { "$numberLong" : "dateAsMilliseconds" } }

I would appreciate if someone can explain me why there is no common format used between MongoDB java driver, mongoexport tool and official docs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously there is *NO* good reason for the Java driver to deviate from the official specification. The only exception are for those dates which cannot be expressed in the ISO8601 format (like B.C. dates...)

As a work around I have extended the `JsonWriter` class and provided two `toJson` static methods as an example of how to use it:

```
package whatever.package.you.like;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import org.bson.BSONException;
import org.bson.BsonContextType;
import org.bson.BsonDocument;
import org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec;
import org.bson.codecs.EncoderContext;
import org.bson.conversions.Bson;
import org.bson.json.JsonMode;
import org.bson.json.JsonWriter;
import org.bson.json.JsonWriterSettings;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

/**
 * A {@link JsonWriter} extension that conforms to the "strict" JSON format
 * specified by MongoDB for data/time values.
 * 
 * The {@link JsonWriter} class provided in the MongoDB Java driver (version
 * 3.2.2) does not conform to official MongoDB specification for strict mode
 * JSON (see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/).
 * This is specifically a problem with the date/time values which get filled
 * with a milliseconds value (i.e. {$date: 309249234098}) instead of the ISO8601
 * date/time (i.e. {$date: "2016-07-14T08:44:23.234Z"}) value which the
 * specification calls for. This extension of {@link JsonWriter} conforms to the
 * MongoDb specification in this regard.
 */
public class ConformingJsonWriter extends JsonWriter {
   private final JsonWriterSettings settings;

   private final Writer writer;

   private boolean writingIndentedDateTime = false;

   /**
    * Creates a new instance which uses {@code writer} to write JSON to.
    *
    * @param writer
    *           the writer to write JSON to.
    */
   public ConformingJsonWriter(final Writer writer) {
      this(writer, new JsonWriterSettings());
   }

   /**
    * Creates a new instance which uses {@code writer} to write JSON to and uses
    * the given settings.
    *
    * @param writer
    *           the writer to write JSON to.
    * @param settings
    *           the settings to apply to this writer.
    */
   public ConformingJsonWriter(final Writer writer,
         final JsonWriterSettings settings) {
      super(writer, settings);
      this.writer = writer;
      this.settings = settings;
      setContext(new Context(null, BsonContextType.TOP_LEVEL, ""));
   }

   private void writeIndentation(int skip) throws IOException {
      for (Context context = getContext()
            .getParentContext(); context != null; context = context
                  .getParentContext()) {
         if (skip-- <= 0) {
            writer.write(settings.getIndentCharacters());
         }
      }
   }

   private static String millisToIso8601(long millis) throws IOException {
      SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'");
      dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
      return dateFormat.format(new Date(millis));
   }

   @Override
   protected void doWriteDateTime(final long value) {
      if ((settings.getOutputMode() == JsonMode.STRICT)
            && (value >= -59014396800000L && value <= 253399536000000L)) {
         try {
            writeStartDocument();
            if (settings.isIndent()) {
               writingIndentedDateTime = true;
               writer.write(settings.getNewLineCharacters());
               writeIndentation(0);
            } else {
               writer.write(" ");
            }
            writer.write("\"$date\" : ");
            writer.write("\"");
            writer.write(millisToIso8601(value));
            writer.write("\"");
            writeEndDocument();
            writingIndentedDateTime = false;
         } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new BSONException("Wrapping IOException", e);
         }
      } else {
         super.doWriteDateTime(value);
      }
   }

   @Override
   protected void doWriteEndDocument() {
      if (writingIndentedDateTime) {
         try {
            writer.write(settings.getNewLineCharacters());
            writeIndentation(1);
            writer.write("}");
            if (getContext()
                  .getContextType() == BsonContextType.SCOPE_DOCUMENT) {
               setContext(getContext().getParentContext());
               writeEndDocument();
            } else {
               setContext(getContext().getParentContext());
            }
         } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new BSONException("Wrapping IOException", e);
         }
      } else {
         super.doWriteEndDocument();
      }
   }

   /**
    * Take a {@link Bson} instance and convert it to "strict" JSON
    * representation with no indentation (read, "NOT pretty printed").
    * 
    * @param bson
    *           The {@link Bson} instance to convert
    * @return The JSON representation.
    */
   public static String toJson(Bson bson) {
      return toJson(bson, new JsonWriterSettings());
   }

   /**
    * Take a {@link Bson} instance and convert it to JSON representation.
    * 
    * @param bson
    *           The {@link Bson} instance to convert
    * @param writerSettings
    *           {@link JsonWriterSettings} that specify details about how the
    *           JSON output should look.
    * @return The JSON representation.
    */
   public static String toJson(Bson bson,
         final JsonWriterSettings writerSettings) {
      BsonDocumentCodec encoder = new BsonDocumentCodec();
      ConformingJsonWriter writer = new ConformingJsonWriter(new StringWriter(),
            writerSettings);
      encoder.encode(writer,
            bson.toBsonDocument(BsonDocument.class,
                  MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry()),
            EncoderContext.builder().isEncodingCollectibleDocument(true)
                  .build());
      return writer.getWriter().toString();
   }
}
```